# Write a program that will generate a receding (going from large to small) black square on a background of colourful rectangles(small to large)

Tags: python, pygame

We have to write a porgram that will generate a receding (going from large to small) black square on a background of rectangles going from small to large from (0,0). The screen is 700 by 700

The problem with my program is that the background of rectangles goes from large to small and the receding square goes from small to big. Can you please help me?

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
RED = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SIZE = (700, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
for x in range(700):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,((random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))),(1*x,1*x,700,700))

for xy in range(700):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(700,700,-xy,-xy))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.time.wait(1)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have to write a porgram that will generate a receding (going from large to small) black square on a background:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(700,700,-xy,-xy))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, size, size))
```

> on a background of rectangles going from small to large from (0,0)

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(1*x,1*x,700,700))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (0, 0, size, size))
```

Note, the black size of the black rectangle decrease, thus you have to to draw a colored rectangle with a size that is one bigger than the black rectangle followed by the black rectangle. Draw the rectangles in a loop with decreasing size. For instance:

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
RED = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SIZE = (700, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

for size in range(700, 0, -1):
    color = ((random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,(0, 0, size+1, size+1))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, size, size))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.time.wait(1)

pygame.quit()
```

[image]